# how can i call a throwable method inside a runnable, for creating a new thread

Tags: java, android

while trying to create a progressbar in android i came across this problem.
i am following this example : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

my problem is that one of my methods i want to call has to be inside a try and catch
how do i do that inside of a runnable?

```
Runnable SendThread = new Runnable() 
{
    try 
    {
        GetAndConvertImagesToPdf();
        mProgStatus = 30;
        mProgress.setProgress(mProgStatus);
        title.setText(R.string.sendingTitle);

    } 
    catch (DocumentException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

i get this error:

"Syntax error on token try, delete this token"

how can i resolve this?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u put the try in the class body its not in any method or block

this is more like it

```
Runnable SendThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            GetAndConvertImagesToPdf();
            mProgStatus = 30;
            mProgress.setProgress(mProgStatus);
            title.setText(R.string.sendingTitle);
        } 
        catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I am not able to answer your question but I have one advice,Try to explore about AsyncTask it will help you to run a background thread and it will let you update your UI thread as well at same time. however good luck for your current question.

link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Happy Coding!